# Problems with the title "References" in \begin{thebibliography} environment

Tags: bibliographies, environments, changes

My problem is that I want to delete the title "references" of thebibliography environment. I would like to build a `\section{7 REFERENCES}` and then use `\vspace{-xxcm}` to move the \bibitem that I wrote.

I'm using article, and I do not want to use biblatex ou bibtex. Furthermore, I'm not a advanced user so I appreciate simple (if exists of course) ways to solve.[image]

obs:
Commands like `\renewcommand\refname{Reference}` simply didn't work in my case.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You said that using the `\renewcommand ...` approach did not work for you.
However, the command you gave (`\renewcommand\refname{Reference}`) does not remove the heading but sets the heading to "Reference".

Try `\renewcommand{\refname}{}`, which overwrites to heading to be blank (the `{}` part)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it depends on wether you are using the babel package or not, and on the documentcalss you are using.

If you are using babel use:

```
\addto{\captionsLANGUAGE>}{\renewcommand{\refname}{{TITLE}}}
```

If you are **not** using babel use:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{TITLE}
```

In TITLE goes the title you want, in LANGUAGE goes the language you are using. You have to put this line before the `\begin{document}` statement.

Depending on the documentclass you are using, it might be necessary to replace`\refname` with `\bibname` (for example, *article* uses `\refname` while *book* uses`\bibname`).

Use one of the following commands in case the previous did not work for you:

If you are using babel:

```
\addto{\captionsLANGUAGE}{\renewcommand{\bibname}{{TITLE}}}
```

If you are **not** using babel:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{TITLE}
```

Here is an example using the babel package in portuguese language, and *article* as the documentclass:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}    
\addto{\captionsportuguese}{\renewcommand{\refname}{{7 REFERÊNCIAS}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{7 REFERÊNCIAS}
\begin{thebibliography}{widest entry}
    \bibitem[1]{item1} {Item 1 bib}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example 1]

To get what you asked for, you have two options: to remove the section line, or to set blank the bibliography title. In the following code, we do the latter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\addto{\captionsportuguese}{\renewcommand{\refname}{{}}} % Here is the change

\begin{document}
\section*{7 REFERÊNCIAS}
\begin{thebibliography}{widest entry}
    \bibitem[1]{item1} {Item 1 bib}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example 2]

Hope this answer your question.